# How to fetch resource value from .resx file stored in my own custom folder location?

Tags: c#, localization

I want to get a resource value from my .resx file that is NOT stored in the local resource folder.

How can I do this?

I am currently using the strongly typed file that is generated, but in this case I can't use the strongly typed as I am building the key (which is a string) in a loop dynamically.

GetLocalResourceObject doesn't seem to work as it only seems to look for the resource file in a specific location.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a path to when using `GetLocalResourceObject`. Bare in mind you may hit problems if the external source is not get compiled.

```
 HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("~/Views/SomeView/Index.cshtml", "Prop");
```

This expects a resx file at the following location.

```
 ~/Views/SomeView/App_LocalResources/Index.cshtml.resx
```

You can also precompile resx resources and create a custom provider to locate them.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the **ResourceManager** like the **StringsResourceManager** used in the article [.NET String Resources](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/StringResources.aspx).